# Chaining string methods (split, gsub) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I'd like to split and do a substitution in a string in one chained command. 
Here's my example including the error message:

```
>> filebase
=> "Ueki_-_Hello_World"
>> filebase.split("_-_").gsub("_"," ")
NoMethodError: private method `gsub' called for ["Ueki", "Hello_World"]:Array
    from (irb):16
```

It works when I save the result of "split" in a temporary variable. Do I really need that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String#split` returns an `Array`. `Array`s don't have a `gsub` method.

It's not clear what it is you are trying you achieve. Is this what you are looking for?

```
filebase.split("_-_").map {|s| s.gsub("_"," ") }
```

Comment: To be technical, it doesn't have a public `gsub` method, just a private one for keyword-like use.

Comment: To be even more technical, `Kernel` has a private `gsub` method, which `Array` inherits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either map or collect:

```
filebase.split("_-_").map {|s| s.gsub("_"," ") }
filebase.split("_-_").collect {|s| s.gsub("_"," ") }
```